# birt detail row divide into two columns

Tags: multiple-columns, birt

Hi i have a report that has many details, I need to divide it into 2 columns. The usual detail row gets enumerated going down like this:

1. List item
2. List item
3. List item
4. List item

but i want it to look like this

1. List item  3. List item
2. List item  4. List item

How do I do that? Is there a sample / link where I can refer to? I was thinking maybe thre is an easier way like a control to add than programming it to divide itself. I cant just divide it by fixed no. coz detail for each category has different counts.
thanks

Comment: Try looking into Cross Tabs.

Comment: hi . I did put style cross tabs but it did nothing..tnx

Comment: Not the style, the report item object - see http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/eclipse_documentation/eclipse_birt_report_guide/topic/org.eclipse.birt.doc/birt/eclipse_birt_report_crosstab.17.7.html

Comment: i did that too but it does not cater to what I am currently looking for. the link shows that crosstabs contain different column fields per section. what I want is just 1 field in a detail row divided into two columns so that it wont appear as very long list going down. tnx

Comment: why cant you make two dataset by using limit in your query...

Comment: that's what I have been trying to do, but I don't know how to access the row count of the dataset. here's is my script this.queryText = this.queryText + "LIMIT"..? I need the row count as it varies.  I need the rowcount/2 ex. 14/2 = LIMIT 7

Comment: I was able to do this using 2 datasets on a subreport. Query has limit but is passed as parameter. I decided to add another column from an outer table that returns item count for each grp. I used that count as parameter of subreport (or subtable) for the limit. I now have 2 columns with dynamic limit. thanks

Answer (score 6):

the "List" element from the BIRT palette should act exactly as you need:

- Drag a list from the palette onto the body of the report
- Bind the list  to the data set in "bindings" tab
- Drag & drop a field from the dataset within the list details
- Set the width of this field as you like, for example something like half-width of a page
- In general properties of the datafield, set property "display" to "inline". Run the report, your items will be split in 2 columns

If you want to combine several datafields in each column:

- insert a grid element in list details, and set its width as required
- In general properties of the grid, set property "display" to "inline"
- Arrange datafields as you like in the grid

Comment: this did the trick as exactly I want but it's inconvenient since it aligns list of items going to next column instead of listing it going down first then display the rest on the next column. I want it this way>>ex. 14 items, list items 1-7 first going down then 8-14 on the next column going down. What it does is display list items no 1,3,5,7,9,11,13 on the 1st column then then 2,4,6,8,10,12,14 on the second. Maybe I'll go with the 2 data sets then not using script, but at least I have learned new trick here. tnx for this info.